# Retryable on WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-retry

I've have a method which is annotated with @Scheduled and @Retryable. This method work fine with Mvc but the same method is not working on Webflux.

The scheduler works fine but Retryable is not happening. This happens only on Webflux.

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "${config.refresh.interval}")
 @Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${config.backoff.delay:999}"))
 public void refreshConfig() {

   // Load config values here

 }

Boot Version - 2.6.7 
spring-retry - 1.3.3
```

Comment: A simple google search shows https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-retry

Comment: Yes that's for WebClient and I'm aware of how to achieve the WebClient retry. The question is for a method retry which doesn't have WebClient usage at all.

Comment: no its not for webclient, its for a `Mono` or `Flux` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#retry-- retry annotation wont work, and without showing your actual usercase we cant show you how to implement it. You asked for how retryable is used in webflux and i have shown you. Stick your function in a producer using fromCallable, and then use retry.